# Knowing when the CLLocationManager has locked in current location

Tags: objective-c, ios

With a CLLocationManager object, you begin by setting the distance filter and desired accuracy:

```
_locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
_locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers;
```

Then you begin updating the device's location:

```
[_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

When is the location locked in? I need to process this location, but don't want to process it until it is fully locked in.

Thanks!

Edit:

Realized the  protocol methods are not being called; not sure why. 
_locationManager.delegate = self;

Answer (score 0):

When you start receiving location updates from the `CLLocationManagerDelegate`, look at the `horizontalAccuracy` property of the received `CLLocation`. Compare it against an appropriate `kCLLocationAccuracyXXX` constant to decide if the value is "good enough" for your needs.

Comment: The delegate methods are never being called for some reason. I am using didUpdateLocations and didFailWithError; neither of them have any output when I try to debug them. I have a custom class LocationController I am using for setting up various location based methods.

Comment: This class is the <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

Comment: I'm talking about the implementation of the `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` or `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` method.

Comment: And don't forget to set the `delegate` property on `_locationManager`.

Comment: I did: _locationManager.delegate = self. I am running on the simulator so I don't know if that has an impact on the method calls. didUpdateLocations seems to get called, but it is not always called.

Comment: What location are you using in the simulator (Debug, Location menu)? You should put this on a device and go run around.

Comment: I just need to lock in 1 location though for the application I am working on. I am using Cupertino.